# Android Music Player - Does the default "Music Player" program store the timestamp of when a song was last played?

Tags: audio, mp3, sqlite

I have a question about the recently played items in the Android (specifically v4.2.2) media library.

Does the default "Music Player" program store the timestamp of when a song was last played? Or does it simply increment a play counter or even just append the song's index to a table? Any explanatory information about the two dynamic playlists: "recently played" and "most played" will be most appreciated.

For background: I am trying to determine the last time an MP3 was played on an Android phone (Samsung Beam2 Android v4.2.2) and any help is very much appreciated. I have rooted the phone and pulled what I think are the media SQL lite databases from here:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/internal.db
/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db
```

Browsing these with an SQL Lite browser I can see all the MP3 files and the "files" table holds columns for "recently_played" and "most_played". However, these columns are empty, so I may have pulled the wrong database. If I found the correct database, what kind of values can I expect to find here? Flags? Indices? Or timestamps?

Any help is very much appreciated, I am an experienced developer but have little experience with Android.

Thank you.﻿

Comment: I have been looking extensively online, and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314288/playcount-for-media-files